# how can i show calculating alert when clicking button

Tags: javascript, html, alert

I'm trying to do exactly like this

`input` + `input` = `output`

A simple form with two inputs for numbers and a plus + symbol between them. You will also have to add the Calculate button after them and make sure it works!

Calculate Functionality: When a user clicks the button an alert message in a pop-up shows up with the message: “The answer of [ ] + [ ] is [ ]." The first two [ ] should be replaced by the numbers that the user has entered in the inputs.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AVhP.jpg)

Comment: Please try some code and post it here if it's not working.

Comment: Okay, so what have you tried so far? Show us where did you get stuck, so we can try and resolve your problem. Unfortunately, this is not a place where you search for solutions for your homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <label>Fist number:</label>
  <input type="number" id="num1" />

  <label>Second number:</label>
  <input type="number" id="num2" />

  <button onclick="calclute()">caclute</button>


  <script>
    function calclute() {
      var num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
      var num2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;

      alert("the answer of " + num1 + " + " + num2 + " is " + 
      (parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2)));

    }
  </script>
```

Comment: I really can't thank you enough

Comment: please check this answer useful